# Python equivalent in javascript's valueOf()

Tags: javascript, python

My legacy javascript code is below.

```
let today = new Date(Date.now());
let todayStr = today.getFullYear() + '-' + addZero(today.getMonth()+1) + '-' + addZero(today.getDate());
let todayStart = (new Date(todayStr + ' 00:00:00')).valueOf()
console.log(todayStart)
```

It's result is `1544454000000`.  That is my server's valid input format.

So I want to migrate this code to Python.
My trial was that use `datetime.fromtimestamp`.
But result was not same to javascript's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Python uses seconds instead of milliseconds. Just multiply by 1000 and cast to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't use milliseconds like JavaScript - it uses seconds. So `1000` in JavaScript would be `1` in Python. So all you have to do is:

```
int(datetime.fromtimestamp) * 1000
```

To fix the language difference.